# git - how to push from multiple devices in the same time

Tags: git

I have a CICD that checkout the git repo, modifies the values in files, and then pushes it back. There is always a pipeline per file. So two pipelines never writes to the same file. But when I am running those pipelines in parallel I get this error:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not
hint: have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to
hint: the same ref. If you want to integrate the remote changes, use
hint: 'git pull' before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Is there a way to safely push the code to the same branch in parallel?

Comment: "*Is there a way to safely push the code to the same branch in parallel?*" No, never. Every pipeline must pull before push. And even that not guarantees push. You need to find a way to serialize pushes. Perhaps push to different branches and then have **one** CI/CD job that integrates all branches and merges them into one master.

Comment: @phd is there a way to checkout only one file and push it, so the push do not affect any other checkouts ?

Comment: No. GIt doesn't pull/push files, GIt doesn't even transfer commits — Git traffics chains of commits (and their references: branches and tags). In your case pull is always required to update local chain of commits; but at the time of push some other CI/CD job could already pushed so another pull would be required and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not track versions of *individual files*, it tracks versions of *your entire repository*. When you commit a change, what you are actually doing is:

1. Adding the changed file's contents as a "blob" in git's object database. This blob doesn't have a name; two files with identical contents share the same blob.
2. Creating a new "tree" object specifying that a particular file name refers to that "blob". The tree lists *all files that exist in that revision*, not just the ones that have been changed.
3. Creating a new "commit" object containing: a reference to that tree; commit message, author, date, etc; and the *parent* commit it was based on.
4. Probably, pointing a particular branch name to the newly created commit object. The history of the branch is found by examining the "parent" stored on each commit, and working backwards.

Blobs, trees, and commits are all immutable; they're referenced by a hash of their content, so it's impossible to change that content and keep the same hash. So once Alice (or CI Job 1) has created a commit with a change in it, Bob (or CI Job 2) can do one of two things:

1. Create a commit *ignoring* Alice's changes - so Alice's commit and Bob's commit have the same parent, and are effectively on separate branches. To combine them, a `git merge` would be needed that created a *third* commit combining the two.
2. Create a commit *based on* Alice's changes - update Bob's working copy first, then make the change, so that Bob can create a commit with Alice's commit as its parent.

Note that a `git rebase` is basically a way of doing option 2 "after the fact" - Bob makes a change, then decides it should have been based on Alice's change, so recreates it on top of Alice's history.

The error you are seeing is that your script is taking option 1, but trying to update the same branch *name* to point to the new *alternative* branch. The remote server is refusing to accept the push because if it points the branch name at Bob's commit, it will be throwing away Alice's commit.

Comment: This answer does a good job of explaining *why*. However, as written, the answer implies that you can merge, or perhaps rebase to fix it, but I think in this case merging is probably the only acceptable solution, since we don't want the pipeline to "lie" about what commit it built and/or tested against.

Comment: @TTT The question implies that the changes are independent anyway, so pretending they happened in a particular sequence rather than in parallel doesn't seem any more of a lie than any other rebase.

Comment: @IMSoP if Alice updates file1 and Bob updates file2, and they are pushing the data at the same time, does git check file hashes for all the files or only for files that were changed? Alice pushes file1, and even file2 (let's imagine Bob already pushed the code ) on remote has a different hash, alice doesn't care about those file2 changes as she cares only about file1. That was my original assumption

Comment: @rholdberh That question has no meaninful answer, because it is based on the wrong mental model. `git push` is not working with individual files, it is working with whole commits. Each commit has a complete directory of which files it contains - a commit is not a *patch*, it is a *snapshot*. So git is not "checking file hashes" at all, it is deciding a) which commits the remote server doesn't have a copy of, and sending over whatever data is needed to have those commits in full; and b) which single commit it should point to as the latest revision for a particular branch name.

Comment: @rholdberh I've expanded the background at the beginning of the answer a bit, in case that makes it clearer for you.